# How can I make this query in Laravel:

Tags: mysql, laravel

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM time_table_rup t 
INNER JOIN gruppa g ON t.group_id = g.gruppa_id 
INNER JOIN discipline d ON t.discipline_id=d.discipline_id 
WHERE sikl = 5 AND t.semestr % 2 = 1
```

Comment: Do you want a raw query, or do you already have models and relationships defined for those tables?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Ahmed Shefeer
I have models and relationships defined for these tables

Comment: So your question is how to execute a query on a mysql database from laravel?

Answer (score 2):

Use query builder like this:

```php
DB::table('time_table_rup AS t')
->join('gruppa AS g', 't.group_id', '=', 'g.gruppa_id')
->join('discipline AS d', 't.discipline_id', '=', 'd.discipline_id')
->where('sikl', 5)
->where(DB::raw('t.semestr % 2'),1)
->get()
```